# Use @country in msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a procedure giving me some data. The procedure is run 4 times with @country changing and giving data from 4 different countries (the data are from differente databases.) In addition to putting the data into a file, I also want to email the result of each country as an csv-file using sp_send_dbmail like showing below.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'xxx',
    @recipients = 'xxx',
    @query = 'SELECT * FROM xxx',
    @subject = 'Addresses from @country',
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Addresses_@country.csv',
    @query_result_separator = ';',
    @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

My question is: Is it possible to use @country from the procedure in @subject and @query_attachment_filename? I have tried, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use a variable:

```
declare @subject nvarchar(255) = N'Addresses from ' + @country;
declare @@query_attachment_filename nvarchar(255) = N'Addresses_@country.csv';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'xxx',
    @recipients = 'xxx',
    @query = 'SELECT * FROM xxx',
    @subject = @subject,
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query_attachment_filename = @query_attachment_filename,
    @query_result_separator = ';',
    @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```